# Flat File Database in C++, Is it possible?

Tags: c++

Flat File Database in C++, Is it possible?

Comment: Yes.  In other words, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 4):

Most flat file databases are written in C++.  This is clear evidence that it is possible.

It is easy enough to make your own, especially if portablity - the ability to take a generated file and move it to another computer or use it with a different compilation of the program - is not required.

```
struct my_record_t {
   ...
};

int read(my_record_t& rec,size_t idx,FILE *f) {
   if(0 > fseek(f,idx*sizeof(rec),SEEK_SET))
      return -1;
   if(1 != fread(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,f))
      return -1;
   return 0;
}

int write(my_record_t& rec,size_t idx,FILE *f) {
   if(0 > fseek(f,idx*sizeof(rec),SEEK_SET))
      return -1;
   if(1 != fwrite(&rec,sizeof(rec),1,f))
      return -1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well i thought they were only in use in php Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try tokyo cabinet: http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/